# Advice on manipulating RRD/XML files to use with pandas/python on windows

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, rrdtool, rrd

I've been scrolling for a while but couldn't find a solution or advice to my particular problem. I'm new to Python and to pandas module/model testing, and I started studying machine learning and predictive time series recently.
I'm currently using python and pandas on Windows Powershell and Visual Studio Code. I have an RRD database exported from a virtual linux machine, from which i should take the data (it only has a date and value columns) to create and validate a model. The thing is that pandas doesn't read RRD files, and its XML file has a weird format. This is what i already tried:

-Installing RRDTool from pip to make a script to save the data to a CSV: kept getting errors regarding RRDTool libraries and header. If i go over to https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/ like the error suggests, last downloadable Cygwin Windows version is really old (2005 and 2007). Is rrdtool deprecated from windows?

-Trying some scripts from here to open XML files and parse through its code: failled because rrd xml file has a weird format to match rrd file.

-Trying to manually adapt the xml file to be parsable: this file has over 50000 rows and i would need to do this again in the future, so it is not desirable.

Also i read that there are pearl scripts for rrd2csv but also require rrd installed (and i don't know pearl).

Is there any way to export a rrd to csv on python - windows? or should I abandon it and try to do it on python - linux, for example?

Thanks for your time reading this.